# Return Custom Object from AuthenticationHandler

Tags: c#, .net-core

I'm attempting to utilize custom authentication from a 3rd party provider - and link this in to .net core 2.0.

I've created the basics...
"TokenAuthenticationHandler"

```
public class TokenAuthenticationHandler : AuthenticationHandler<TokenAuthenticationOptions>
{
    public TokenAuthenticationHandler(IOptionsMonitor<TokenAuthenticationOptions> options, 
        ILoggerFactory logger, 
        UrlEncoder encoder, 
        ISystemClock clock) 
        : base(options, logger, encoder, clock)
    {

    }

    protected override async Task<AuthenticateResult> HandleAuthenticateAsync()
    {
        // Get the API key
        var token = new AuthToken
        {
            ApiKey = GetKeyValue(Options.ApiKeyName),
            Username = GetKeyValue(Options.UsernameKeyName),
            Password = GetKeyValue(Options.PasswordKeyName),
            IpAddress = Context.Connection.RemoteIpAddress.ToString()
        };

        // setup the auth repo and identity
        var authRepo = new AuthRepository(token);
        var identity = new TokenIdentity(authRepo);

        // Check the identity
        if (identity.IsAuthenticated)
        {
            var ticket = new AuthenticationTicket(new ClaimsPrincipal(identity), null, "exttoken");
            var result = AuthenticateResult.Success(ticket);
            return result;
        }

        // Authentication failed
        return AuthenticateResult.NoResult();
    }

    protected string GetKeyValue(string keyName)
    {
        return Request
            .Headers?
            .SingleOrDefault(a => a.Key == keyName)
            .Value
            .FirstOrDefault();
    }
}
```

"TokenAuthenticationOptions"

```
public class TokenAuthenticationOptions : AuthenticationSchemeOptions
{
    public string ApiKeyName { get; set; } = "X-APIKEY";
    public string UsernameKeyName { get; set; } = "X-USERNAME";
    public string PasswordKeyName { get; set; } = "X-PASSWORD";
    public string CookieName { get; set; } = "MTDATA";
}
```

This all works perfectly, the user is authenticated, or not (via a 401 error), and the controller is called...

However... I somehow need to get the "AuthRepository" object from here - back to my controller, as this is how I interact with the 3rd party system.

I attempted to resolve this with a custom IIdentity implementation, as seen below;

```
public class TokenIdentity : IIdentity
{
    public string AuthenticationType { get; } = "exttoken";
    public bool IsAuthenticated { get; }
    public string Name { get; }
    public AuthRepository AuthenticationRepository { get; }

    public TokenIdentity(AuthRepository authRepository)
    {
        AuthenticationRepository = authRepository;
        IsAuthenticated = AuthenticationRepository.Authenticate();
        if (IsAuthenticated)
            Name = AuthenticationRepository.GetCurrentUser()?.Name;
    }
}
```

Within my controller, I then attempt to get the Identity with `HttpContext.User.Identity` - however at this point within the controller, my customer "TokenIdentity" has been transformed into a "ClaimsPrinciple", the error listed is:

> System.InvalidCastException: 'Unable to cast object of type
>   'System.Security.Claims.ClaimsIdentity' to type
>   'X.X.X.WebAPI.Authentication.TokenIdentity'.'

Any ideas?   Attempting to call the authRepository again is not an option, as there is overheads associated with the authorization and access request - its therefore vital I continue to utilize the existing authRepo object.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Resolved this issue with the following change to the HandleAuthenticateAsync;

```
// Check the identity
if (identity.IsAuthenticated)
{
    var ticket = new AuthenticationTicket(new ClaimsPrincipal(identity), null, "exttoken");
    var result = AuthenticateResult.Success(ticket);
    Request.HttpContext.Items["auth"] = authRepo;
    return result;
}
```

I can then access the authRepo with:

```
var authRepo = (AuthRepository)HttpContext.Items["auth"];
```

Is it a good idea to store this object in `HttpContext.Items`?